# Need Help Solving Logarithmic Equation $2(5)^x=3^{x+1}$

Tags: calculus

Need Help Solve Logarithmic Equation. Thanks Gary

[image: $2\cdot 5^x = 3^x+1$]

$$2(5)^x = 3^{x+1}$$

Comment: I think I have to do log2(5)=3^x+1

Comment: Is my edit correct?

Comment: I've typeset your equation above. Look to see how to do it, for future reference.

Comment: Can you show me how to do this step by step? I have a simlar equation that I need to solve that is like this

Comment: Rewrite both sides using the same base.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean $2(5)^x = 3^{x + 1}$, you can take the natural log of both sides.

$$\ln(2(5)^x) = \ln(3^{x + 1})$$

Then the product/sum rule:
$$\ln(2)+\ln(5^x) = \ln(3^{x + 1})$$
Then the exponents:
$$\ln(2)+x \ln(5) = (x+1)\ln(3)$$
Distribute:
$$\ln(2)+x \ln(5) = x\ln(3)+\ln(3)$$
Collect like terms:
$$x\ln(5) - x\ln(3) = \ln(3)-\ln(2)$$
Factor:
$$x(\ln(5) - \ln(3)) = \ln(3)-\ln(2)$$
Difference/quotient:
$$x \ln(\frac{5}{3}) = \ln(\frac{3}{2})$$
Divide:
$$x  = \dfrac{\ln(\frac{3}{2})}{\ln(\frac{5}{3})}$$

Not pretty, but that's one way to write the solution.

Comment: does in reprsent Log?

Comment: That's unimportant, @user73122: the given solution for $\,x\,$ is true (and the same, of course) no matter what basis you choose for the logarithm.

Comment: As a matter of fact one can choose a function $f(x)$ which acts like log function. ;)

Comment: $\ln$ (uppercase LN) means $\log_e$ where $e$ is the irrational number $2.718...$  If you're solving a problem where the bases are the same, use log with that base.  If they are different, go with $\ln$.  That's not *always* the best way, but should steer you in the right direction.

Comment: You both failed to answer OP's question in the above comment.